# java mergeSort weird output

Tags: java

```
public static int[] mergeArray(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];

    int i = 0; // to index array a
    int j = 0; // to index array b

    for (int k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
        if(a.length == i+1) {
            result[k] = b[j-1];
            j++;
        }else if(b.length == j+1) {
            result[k] = a[i-1];
            i++;
        }else if(a[i] > b[j]) {
            result[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }else if(a[i] < b[j]) {
            result[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// this method does the same thing as sortArray but much more efficiently
// it uses meregeArray
public static int[] mergeSortArray(int[] poop) {
    int[] p1 = new int[poop.length/2];
    int[] p2 = new int[poop.length-p1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<p1.length; i++) {
        p1[i] = poop[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<p2.length; i++) {
        p2[i] = poop[i+p1.length - 1];
    }
    sortArray(p1);
    sortArray(p2);
    return mergeArray(p1, p2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] poop = new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    String s = "";
    for(int i : mergeSortArray(poop)){
        s += i + ", ";
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The code takes a int[] and converts it into two, then it sorts it, but the error seems to be in the output as you can see below it outputs two 6's which is odd and I'm not sure, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

here is the output:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9,

Thanks everyone who helps :)

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? Do you get the expected results at p1, p2 after the inital run of `mergeSortArray` (Hint - NO)? And what is `sortArray(p1)`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not that smarter than everybody else in the Universe. Internally Java uses mergeSort and other efficient algorithms as you can see for example at the [source code of java.util.Arrays](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29)

Secondly, I believe that there is a bug in line

```
    p2[i] = poop[i+p1.length - 1]; // bad
    p2[i] = poop[i+p1.length];     // good
```

Because of this bug array is splitted wrongly removing 10 from output

And thirdly there is a bug in `mergeArray`, it should be

```
    if(a.length == i) {
        result[k] = b[j];
        j++;
    } else if(b.length == j) {
        result[k] = a[i];
        i++;
```

This is the result of duplication of "6"

And as TDG said, learning to debug your code is a crucial skill that you should learn.